# Translate numeric status codes in Symfony2 and SonataAdmin

Tags: php, symfony, translation, sonata-admin

What is the best way to handle string representations and translations of numeric codes in Symfony2?

Suppose I have an entity like this:

```
<?php

class Message
{
    const STATUS_NEW       = 0;
    const STATUS_SENT      = 1;
    const STATUS_DELIVERED = 2;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $status = self::STATUS_NEW;

    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }
}
```

On the front-end and in the SonataAdmin backend I do not want to show numeric codes but strings. E.g 'New', 'Sent', and 'Delivered'. But I also want to be able to translate these strings (e.g. in Dutch 'Nieuw', 'Verzonden' and 'Afgeleverd').

So there are two conversion steps: first from the numeric code to a string or translation key, and then to the localised string.

Where and how do I best do these conversions? Both in the front end in my own controllers/views and in a SonataAdmin based backed?

Comment: Are you already defining those strings ('New', 'Sent', and 'Delivered') somewhere in your code? Or in a database?

Comment: No, not yet. I'm looking for the best place to put those. I think the translations will be the easiest to figure out. But what is the best place to go from those numeric codes to strings?

Comment: I do agree with you that the translation part is the easy one. What I have done, is put those key/value pairs in a config file that I load in the database with the doctrine fixture bundle and then translate them using the Translatable extension from the DoctrineExtension bundle. But definitely not sure if it is a good solution or not...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I were you, I would add a method to my Class Message

```
public function getStatusString() {
    return 'message.status.'.$this->status;
}
```

And then, handle it in your translation file like this:

**message.en.xlf**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>message.status.0</source>
                <target>New</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="2">
                <source>message.status.1</source>
                <target>Sent</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="3">
                <source>message.status.2</source>
                <target>Delivered</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Answer (score 0):

YoH's answer is a nice solution to this problem.

However when I implement my status codes I like to have the message and status codes right inside my entity class.

Therefor I wan't to show my solution which is not as good as YoH's solution because it lacks internationalization but works good for me.

```
class Message
{
    ... 
    const STATUS_NEW       = 0;
    const STATUS_SENT      = 1;
    const STATUS_DELIVERED = 2;

    ...
    public static $statusCodes = array(
        Message::STATUS_NEW => "New",
        Message::STATUS_SENT => "Sent",
        Message::STATUS_DELIVERED => "Delivered"
    );

    public static function getStatusCodes()
    {
        return self::$statusCodes;
    }

    public function getReadableStatus()
    {
        if (!is_null($this->getStatus())) {
            return self::$statusCodes[$this->getStatus()];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And in the Sonata Admin Class for Message change the field in configureFormFields() to:

```
->add('status', 'choice', array(
                    'label' => "current Status",
                    'help' => "What's that status of the message ?",
                    'choices' => Message::getStatusCodes()
                )
            )
```

And if you want to show the value in the list then change configureListFields() to:

```
->add('status', 'string', array('template' => 'YourBundleName:Admin:message_list_status_field.html.twig'))
```

And create a twig named 'message_list_status_field.html.twig':

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}
{% block field %}
    <div>
        {{ object.readableStatus }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```